# Lambda invoke unhandled, timing out after 3 seconds?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

Have the following lambda function and dynamodb defined via terraform:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-1"  # Change to your desired region
  access_key              = "test"       # Access key for LocalStack
  secret_key              = "test"       # Secret key for LocalStack
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true

  endpoints {
    dynamodb    = "http://localhost:4566"  # LocalStack DynamoDB endpoint
    lambda      = "http://localhost:4566"
    iam         = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_execution_role" {
  name = "lambda_execution_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_dynamodb_access" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_execution_policy" {
  name   = "lambda_execution_policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        Effect   = "Allow",
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Action   = "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        Effect   = "Allow",
        Resource = aws_lambda_function.add_user_post.arn
      }
      # Add more permissions as needed
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "add_user_post" {
  function_name = "AddUserPost"
  handler       =   "addUserPostFunction.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  filename      = data.archive_file.lambda_function_add_user_post.output_path  # ZIP file containing your Python code
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.arn
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda_function_add_user_post.output_path)

  environment {
    variables = {
      TABLE_NAME = "UserProfileTable"
    }
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_function_add_user_post" {
  type          = "zip"
  source_dir    = "${path.module}/Source"
  output_path   = "${path.module}/lambda_function_add_user_post.zip"


}
```

DynamoDB:

```
 provider "aws" {
      region                  = "us-east-1"  # Change to your desired region
      access_key              = "test"       # Access key for LocalStack
      secret_key              = "test"       # Secret key for LocalStack
      skip_credentials_validation = true
      skip_requesting_account_id = true
    
    
      endpoints {
        dynamodb    = "http://localhost:4566"  # LocalStack DynamoDB endpoint
        lambda      = "http://localhost:4566"
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "users_table" {
      name           = "UserProfileTable"
      billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"  # Or use "PAY_PER_REQUEST" for on-demand capacity
      read_capacity  = 5
      write_capacity = 5
      hash_key = "UserID"
      range_key = "PostID"
    
      attribute {
        name = "UserID"
        type = "N"
      }
    
      attribute {
        name = "PostID"
        type = "N"
      }
    
    
    
      tags = {
        Name    = "dynamodb-table-1"
        Environment = "production"
      }
    }
```

And then the .py function that the lambda executes:

```
import boto3
import os


dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Your DynamoDB table name
        table_name = os.environ["TABLE_NAME"]

        # Sample data to be added to DynamoDB
        item = {
            'userid': '1',
            'postid': '1',
            'content': 'Yay!',
        }

        # DynamoDB put operation
        table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
        result = table.put_item(Item=item)

        print('Item added to DynamoDB:', result)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Item added to DynamoDB successfully',
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error adding item to DynamoDB:', e)

        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'Error adding item to DynamoDB',
        }
```

`Terraform apply`ing the two infrastructure components yields no errors, and I can check their existence via `awslocal dynamodb list-tables` or `awslocal lambda list-functions` and they return the expected values.

However, when running: `awslocal --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name AddUserPost --payload '{}' output.json`

I get

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

The `output.json` yields:
`{"errorMessage":"2024-02-10T16:42:23Z cd163c6c-75d4-4be2-9539-cec447c3624a Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"}`

The `unhandled` functionerror made me think the problem was with the handler defined in the lambda function, but I have tripled checked the syntax/spelling of this and I am pretty sure it correct. Not sure how to proceed.

Edit: From Helder's below answer, modifying the type of data in the insert was necessary. This removed one error, but then led to the `invoke` causing a failure to connect to the endpoint. This [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749489/getting-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url-error-with-boto3-when-deploying) has an answer which states that the boto3 runtime should set the `endpoint_url` = 'http://host.docker.internal:4566`. Unclear to me *why* this is necessary, but it fixed the problem fully.

Comment: 3 seconds is the default timeout for a Lambda - have you tried to increase it?

Comment: Does your Lambda function have internet access? Please check if it has internet access. 
I do have same problem while working with this.
Also check time limit set for your lambda function in configuration of your lambda function.

Comment: If you comment all the DB operations in your lambda, just return the statusCode, does it work?  ... trying to narrow down if this is a problem wiht the lambda or the DB

Comment: You are granting `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` so access should not be a problem ... and adding just one record should be less than 3 seconds ... I don't think that increasing the timeout will do anything ... have you tried this in an actual AWS environment?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda if I comment out the dynamoDB stuff I get `{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}`  and no issue. So it must be with the dynamoDB no?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I have not tried it in an AWS environment. I am doing this only via localstack and don't actually have an AWS environment set up.

Comment: ye, all points to the issue been the DynamoDB in localstack  ... and the error output does not help, did you try increasing the timeout? ... going to try this in my AWS environment see what I get

Comment: I get a "better error" when I try in AWS  `Error adding item to DynamoDB: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key UserID in the item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error is in the data you are trying to put in DynamoDB

In your table attribute declaration we can see:

```txt
      attribute {
        name = "UserID"
        type = "N"
      }
    
      attribute {
        name = "PostID"
        type = "N"
      }
```

You have to keep that same case when we call the `table.put_item(Item=item)`

I got it to work like this:

```py
        item = {
            'UserID': 1,
            'PostID': 1,
            'content': 'Yay!',
        }
```

I can see the item created correctly in the table:
[image]

---

Full disclosure I tested directly in AWS not using localstack, from the comments it seems that localstack might be swallowing the error and letting the lambda timeout

Comment: I implemented the change. This was certainly causing an error and I made the fix. Running the `lambda invoke` now returns: 
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
The localstack logs lists: "Error adding item to DynamoDB: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost4566" and nothing is added to the table. I don't understand this error as I can execute `awslocal lambda list-functions` and see my function returned.

Comment: See the edit to the question... why would I need to set the boto3 config (in the .py file) to http://host.docker.internal:4566 instead of http://localhost:4566?

Comment: @Runeaway3 I'm glad this worked for you! ... I would strongly recommend you to test directly on AWS when you run into issues; You are already using terraform, you can just destroy all the infra once you are done testing

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout of a Lambda function is 3 seconds. Your lambda did not finish the execution within 3 seconds and therefore was stooped.
You can increase this timeout up to 15 minutes.
I would start with increasing it to 30 seconds, so you can start and understand why the execution is slow.
I assume you will catch what is going on if you will give the lambda more time to run.